# router.push() waits for getServerSideProps() before performing the navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm currently using Next.js 13.1 with the *pages* directory (not using React Server components yet). In my application, when I use `router.push()` to navigate from page A to page B, I've noticed that the router waits for the `getServerSideProps()` of the page B to complete before performing the navigation.

This brings me to two questions:

1. Is this behaviour expected? I couldn't find any information on the official Next.js documentation indicating that `router.push()` is a blocking operation
2. If this behaviour is expected, should we handle page transitions only at a global level, as mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerevents) in the documentation? If the router performed the client-side navigation immediately, handling the loading would be delegated to the destination page and we could implement specific loading UIs for each page (e.g. different skeletons for different pages)